# Module build failed

Tags: reactjs

I get this 2 errors in my terminal.

```
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;;base64,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" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "data:" URIs.
ERROR in data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;;base64,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     
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;;base64,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" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "data:" URIs.
    at D:\Projects\Crud App\crud-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:832:25
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\Projects\Crud App\crud-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (D:\Projects\Crud App\crud-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at Object.processResource (D:\Projects\Crud App\crud-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:829:8)
    at processResource (D:\Projects\Crud App\crud-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:220:11)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (D:\Projects\Crud App\crud-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:171:10)
    at runLoaders (D:\Projects\Crud App\crud-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:398:2)
    at NormalModule._doBuild (D:\Projects\Crud App\crud-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:819:3)
    at NormalModule.build (D:\Projects\Crud App\crud-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:963:15)
    at D:\Projects\Crud App\crud-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1371:12

ERROR in [entry] [initial]
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
during rendering of asset asset/inline|data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;;base64,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

webpack compiled with 2 errors
```

I'm just created a new react app and `npm install semantic-ui-react semantic-ui-css` and updated index.js as `import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'`

Then,I removed the default header from App.js

```
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

An empty react runs but it gives these 2 errors. I installed node modules again but the errors reamains.

Comment: Can you share both index.js and package.json?

Answer (score 0):

In another site i saw this post stating :

There are 2 semicolons ' ;; ' somewhere inside semantic.min.css in fomantic-ui-css folder, all you have to do is cntrl + f and search for ;; and remove 1 semicolon , save and compile. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is extremely annoying. To workaround it, I created `@semantic-ui-react/css-patch` which works with `semantic-ui-css` & `semantic-ui-less`.

To use, first install it:

```
yarn add --dev @semantic-ui-react/css-patch
```

or

```
npm install --dev @semantic-ui-react/css-patch
```

Add it as a postinstall script to your package.json

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "semantic-ui-css-patch"
    }
}
```

I had to clear the cache before it would work with:

```
del node_modules npm cache clean --force npm install npm start
```